# Question on a proof that $\sum_p 1/p$ diverges

Tags: analysis, proof-explanation

> The sum $\sum_p1/p$ over all $p$ diverges.

Sketch proof. First note that if $s>1$ then $\sum_{n>0}n^{-s} = \prod_p 1/(1-p^{-s})$ where the product is over all primes $p$. Now, letting $s\to 1$, LHS tends to $\infty$ so the product $1/(1-p^{-1})$ diverges, so the corresponding sum of $p^{-1}$ diverges.

I can't understand the last part. so $\infty =\prod_p 1/(1-p^{-1}) = \prod_p\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1/p^k$. How does this imply $\sum_p 1/p$ diverges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\prod_p 1/(1-p^{-1})$ diverges if and only if $\sum_p -\ln{(1-p^{-1})}$ diverges.

Now, what is the ratio between $(-\ln{(1-p^{-1})})$ and $p^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider

$$ \prod_{p\space prime}(1-\frac{x}{p}) = f(x). $$

Then $$ f(x) = 1+\sum_{p = 2}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^{number\space of\space primes\space composing\space p}}{p}. $$

Can you take if from here?